# suddenly "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, pip, pyimagej

I am coding a automation interface using tkinter
i try yesterday that's code, very good working but suddenly faced with an error that says "image "pyimage2" doesn't exist",

```
# python3 app.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/QT/CodTubify/src/app.py", line 163, in <module>
    image_1 = canvas.create_image(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2819, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2805, in _create
    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

here main code

```
window = Tk()
window.title("ExLog")
window.geometry("1092x506")
window.configure(bg = "#171435")

'''for custom cursor'''
#cursor_path=relative_to_assets("@Busy.ani")
#window['cursor']=cursor=cursor_path

'''For Custom title bar'''
#window.overrideredirect(1)
#window.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor","#35F331")


'''For Icon'''
#window.iconbitmap(relative_to_assets("icon2.ico"))

#메인 프레임
image_file = PhotoImage(file='./gui/Primary_Window/assets/image_1.png')  # 'image_path.png'를 실제 이미지 파일 경로로 교체해야 합니다.
canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#494B69",
    height = 506,
    width = 930,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)
canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
background_image = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_1.png"))
image_1 = canvas.create_image(
    566.0,
    253.0,
    image=background_image,
    anchor='nw'
)
```

Comment: When calling `PhotoImage`, try passing in `mater=canvas`. That is just a guess as you haven't posted a fully working [mre].

Comment: @TheLizzard: you have a typo in your comment: it should be `master` rather than `mater`.